# How do I set my media player in android studio kotlin to work with alarm volume?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to get my media player to work with the alarm volume and not media volume. I have tried this, but it is not working, any suggestions? Also, am I am looking to change the sound file at some point, can the solution be used with a variable?

```
        val mediaPlayer1 = MediaPlayer.create(context2, R.raw.geese)
                                                                                                                                
        mediaPlayer1.setAudioAttributes(AudioAttributes.Builder().setUsage((AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM)).build())
        mediaPlayer1.start()
        mediaPlayer1.setLooping(true)
```

Comment: Media player consume media volume only... What you're expecting please provide context more

Comment: I want to play the media file on an alarm that goes off. I want the media file to play off of the alarm setting volume. I don't know how to be more blunt then this, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to this problem.

Use below code as explained.

First declare the media player as shown below

```
private var thePlayer: MediaPlayer? = null
```

Now use below code to create and play the alarm sound.

```
try {
        thePlayer = MediaPlayer()
        thePlayer?.setAudioAttributes(AudioAttributes.Builder().setFlags(AudioAttributes.FLAG_AUDIBILITY_ENFORCED)
            .setLegacyStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM)
            .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM)
            .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION).build())
        thePlayer?.setDataSource(context, RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM))
        thePlayer?.isLooping = true
        thePlayer?.prepare()
        thePlayer?.start()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
```

To stop the media player use the below code.

```
try {
        thePlayer?.stop()
        thePlayer?.release()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
```

**Note: Every time you stop the player, make sure to release the player since it creates the new instance of media player every time it is called.**